# Convolution Properties

Tags: linear-algebra, fourier-analysis, linear-programming, convolution, signal-processing

I have a quick question about certain algebraic properties of convolution. If I have 3 functions $f(x)$, $g(x)$ and $h(x)$, is the following true?

$\Big[ f(x) \cdot g(x)\Big] \circ h(x) = \Big[f(x) \circ h(x)\Big] \cdot g(x)$

Where "$\cdot$" and "$\circ$" are multiplication and convolution respectively.

Answer (score 2):

Did you try writing out these products? The first expression is $$[(fg) \circ h](x) = \int f(y) g(y) h(x-y) \, dy.$$
The second is
$$ [(f \circ h) g](x) = \left(\int f(y) h(x-y) \, dy \right) g(x).$$

These are clearly not the same. For instance, if $h$ is constant the first expression is indepedent of $x$.

Comment: Thank you, it is clear now, there are not the same at all